# PHP on IIS doesn't load sqlsrv extension

Tags: php, iis, sql-server

I'm trying to put together a page that can submit data from a form to an MSSQL database via PHP. I've got PHP installed successfully (`phpinfo()` runs fine even on a remote computer) but it will not load the [sqlsrv extension](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/). I know that I'm editing the right `php.ini` file because I have another extension added (wincache) and it is loading fine, confirmed with both `phpinfo()` and `get_loaded_extensions()`.

The logs aren't telling me anything. PHP Manager on IIS is telling me that the sqlsrv extension files are enabled. I've restarted the website, the server, and the computer, and nothing's working.

I'm using PHP 7.1.1 on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine. It's running in x64 mode, Non-Thread Safe. I've made sure that the extension files I enabled are the x64, non-thread-safe ones. I don't know what else to check or what more info I need to provide.

**EDIT:** I ran `php-cgi.exe` as [this page](https://forums.iis.net/t/1162267.aspx) suggested, and it came out with the error mesages:

```
[31-Mar-2017 22:38:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[31-Mar-2017 22:38:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Does this mean that the problem is in the extension DLLs themselves? How would I even go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like the slqsrv extension doesn't yet support PHP 7.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/137)

At the time of writing (July 2017) it looks like the [preview version](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.1.3-Windows) is available for download so I guess the production version can't be far away

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured it out by now, but for anyone else getting errors like those, make sure you are using the correct version of the DLL ie. `php_sqlsrv_VERSION_THREADSAFETY_ARCHITECTURE.dll`. So put `php_sqlsrv_71_nts_x86.dll` or the one that is compatible with your machine and setup.